# For cricket project: Want to count bowlers spell and over

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on cricket project. So i have to display that blower's spell and which over is running in current spell. 
You can see screenshot here

[image: Bowlers Over]

For Ex.
As in screenshot there is 4 bowler `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`.

- When `B1` bowling 1st over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 1`
- When `B2` bowling 2nd over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 1`
- When `B1` bowling 3rd over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 2`
- When `B2` bowling 4th over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 2`

Now bowler is change

- When `B3` bowling 5th over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 1`
- When `B4` bowling 6th over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 1`
- When `B3` bowling 7th over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 2`
- When `B4` bowling 8th over then `spell = 1` and `spellover = 2`

Now again bowler change and B1 and B2 is ready for bowling

- When `B1` bowling 9th over then `spell = 2` and `spellover = 1`
- When `B2` bowling 10th over then `spell = 2` and `spellover = 1`

I want exactly above record of `spell` and `spellover` from database. When bowlers bowling continuous link break it means bowler's one spell is over.

Here you can see my database record

[image: Database_Record]

If any have idea in linq view then also you can suggest me how to do this in linq view.

Comment: is this homework? You've given us what you want to do. What have you tried to do to solve this already?

Comment: @RichBenner No this is not homework. This my task in my office. I am already try this using "sql with" but i cant find right way.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea:
1.Define a class ,you can name it bowlers or whatever is appropriate

```
class bowlers
        {
            public string bowlerid { get; set; }
            public int spell { get; set; }
            public int spellOver { get; set; }`enter code here`
        }
```

2.Populate the list with values from database.I have populated manually as:

```
List<bowlers> temp = new List<bowlers>();
            temp.Add(new bowlers{bowlerid="1"});
            temp.Add(new bowlers{bowlerid="2"});
            temp.Add(new bowlers{bowlerid="3"}); 
            temp.Add(new bowlers{bowlerid="4"});
```

3.Sort the lsit by bowler id
 var lst= temp.OrderByDescending(x=>x.bowlerid);

4.Finally you need to define the logic to set the spell and spell over.You can set the spell

You can do it as.

```
string current=temp[0].bowlerid;
var result1=temp.SkipWhile(x=>x.bowlerid!=current).Select<bowlers,bowlers>(x=>{spell=x.spell;//update current 
 return new bowlers{bowlerid=x.bowlerid,spell=spell+1}});
```

You need to update the current variable depending upon the scenario.

Comment: :i am tried this its not working. we have to count spellover and spell manually so  i think this solution didn't work for this issue. From database we only got Over numbers, BowlerId, BowlerName